# How can we make a spacer view with automatic width between two views inside UIStackview?

Tags: uikit

If we have 2 labels inside UIStackView, and I want to set a flexible width between them like this image:

[image]

what is the best way? in SwiftUI there is a function named: Spacer() , is there something similar in UIKit?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a UIView to the stack to push each view in the UIStackView:

hStack:

```
 hStack.axis = .horizontal
 hStack.addArrangedSubview(label1)
 hStack.addArrangedSubview(UIView.spacer(for: .horizontal))
 hStack.addArrangedSubview(label2)
```

constraints:

```
hStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
hStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: "depending on your view").isActive = true
hStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: "depending on your view").isActive = true
hStack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

and the extension to make this work:

```
// MARK: - Spacer
extension UIView {

    static func spacer(size: CGFloat = .greatestFiniteMagnitude, for layout: NSLayoutConstraint.Axis = .horizontal) -> UIView {
        let spacer = UIView()
        
        if layout == .horizontal {
            let constraint = spacer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size)
            constraint.priority = .defaultLow
            constraint.isActive = true
        } else {
            let constraint = spacer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size)
            constraint.priority = .defaultLow
            constraint.isActive = true
        }
        return spacer
    }
}
```

Side note:
You may get an error that

> This NSLayoutConstraint is being configured with a constant that
> exceeds internal limits

... so I would rather recommend creating a UIView as a container and then pin each label to the sides of the container (leading, trailing) where each label also has a widthAnchor (if you don't want the text to extend).